# VBA Find row number of first visible row after filter

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting to get the row number of the first visible row after I filter the data. I need the row number so I can select the top cell in that respective row to select all cells below the active cell. I am very much a beginner to VBA so I'm not familiar with essentially any of it.

Here's the example of the code I need to modify:

```
Dim bidNum As String
Dim bidFull As String

bidNum = "123" 'sample number
bidFull = "Bid-" + bidNum + ".csv"

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PriceExp").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=bidFull    'filters data by Bid #

Range("B####", Range("B####").End(xlDown)).Value = "sample name" '#### is where I need to know the current row number after data is filtered
Range("C####", Range("C####").End(xlDown)).Value = "sample state"
'etc. for more columns
```

Comment: First you don't need to `Select` anything, you can avoid it and just use `Range("YourRange").Value = "something"`. The same goes to `ActiveCell`

Comment: @ShaiRado - Thanks for the tip. I really don't know much about VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the rows visible after the filter, you can `Set` a `Range` object using `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` property of the `ListObject`.

After, you need to loop through the `Areas` of the Non-Contiguous Filtered range.

You can set each column `Range`, and by using the `Application.Union` command you can merge ranges together.

Read [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-union-method-excel) more about the `Union` function.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub FillColumnAccordingToFilteredRows()

Dim bidNum As String
Dim bidFull As String

Dim PriceLObj As ListObject

bidNum = "123" 'sample number
bidFull = "Bid-" + bidNum + ".csv"

Set PriceLObj = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PriceExp") ' set the ListObject

PriceLObj.Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=bidFull  ' filters data by Bid #

Dim VisRng As Range, VisArea As Range, VisRow As Range
Dim ColBRng As Range, ColCRng As Range

' get the visible range of the filteres list object
Set VisRng = PriceLObj.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

' === set column B and column C Range ===
For Each VisArea In VisRng.Areas ' loop through areas in non-contigous filtered range

    ' loop through rows in area
    For Each VisRow In VisRng.Rows
        If VisRow.Row <> 1 Then ' not header row
            ' set and Merge ranges for column B range
            If Not ColBRng Is Nothing Then
                Set ColBRng = Application.Union(ColBRng, Range("B" & VisRow.Row))
            Else
                Set ColBRng = Range("B" & VisRow.Row)
            End If

            ' set and Merge ranges for column C range
            If Not ColCRng Is Nothing Then
                Set ColCRng = Application.Union(ColCRng, Range("C" & VisRow.Row))
            Else
                Set ColCRng = Range("C" & VisRow.Row)
            End If
        End If
    Next VisRow
Next VisArea

' make sure column B range is not empty (otherwise will pop an error)
If Not ColBRng Is Nothing Then ColBRng.Value2 = "sample name"

' make sure column C range is not empty (otherwise will pop an error)
If Not ColCRng Is Nothing Then ColCRng.Value2 = "sample state"

End Sub
```