# Excel VBA: Assigning a variable to the value of the first cell from results of an AdvancedFilter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the value of the first filter result that is in column C. The headers are on A5 to J5 and then the results are below. Pointing to C6 gives me the value of the first row in the database when it isn't filtered. I've read online that using

```
Range("C" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value
```

Would return the value as this takes into account that some of the rows are filtered out, but this doesn't work for me. I tried putting it in my GetNextResult subroutine below where I have Set the FilteredData Range variable, and it prompts Compile Error, Invalid or Unqualified Reference.

Just to make it clear, the first subroutine, FilterData, is actually the one that filters the data. The second subroutine, GetNextResult, calls on FilterData() but the purpose of this subroutine is to insert the value of each result into a textbox, one by one upon each execution of this macro.

Not that it's particularly relevant to the issue but in case it's important, the reason I want the value of the first result when filtered is for the purposes of a counter. I'm looking to make it so every time the GetNextResult macro sends the next result to the text boxes the counter goes up by one, so that the user can keep track of how many they've cycled through and not get to the point where they don't realise they're seeing the same results over and over. I figured, if I can get the value of the first filtered row then I can make an if statement say that if the textbox contains this value then make sure counter is 1, and that is the reset point.

```
Public Sub FilterData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    Dim CriteriaRange As Range
    Set CriteriaRange = ws.Range("A2", "C3")

    If Range("C3").Value = "Any" Then
    Set CriteriaRange = ws.Range("A2", "B3")
    End If

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A5", "J" & LastRow)



    DataRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=CriteriaRange, Unique:=False

    Call last_used_sort

    If Not DataRange.Columns(1).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 1 Then

        Call ShowAll
        MsgBox "No Results"        

        Exit Sub

    End If


End Sub
```

```
Public Sub GetNextResult()


    FilterData


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database")

    Dim header As String
    header = "Cards"

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("A5", "J" & LastRow)

    Dim FilteredData As Range
    Set FilteredData = DataRange.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


    If CurrentRow + 1 > FilteredData.Cells.Count Then
        CurrentRow = 1
    End If


    CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1

    With FilteredData
    first_row = Range("C" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value
    End With
    Debug.Print first_row


    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Variant
    Static counter As Long

    counter = counter + 1

    If counter = Quick_Insert_Range Then
    counter = 1
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Cardcounter").TextFrame.Characters.Text = counter


    For Each cell In FilteredData

        i = i + 1
        If i = CurrentRow Then
            Call ShowAll


            TextboxName = "txt1"
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName).DrawingObject.Text = cell.Offset(0, 2)

            TextboxName2 = "txt2"
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName2).DrawingObject.Text = cell.Offset(0, 3)

            TextboxName3 = "txt3"
            ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName3).DrawingObject.Text = cell.Offset(0, 4)


            If ActiveSheet.Shapes(TextboxName).DrawingObject.Text = header Then

                Call GetNextResult
            End If

            Call quick_artwork


        Else
            Call ShowAll

        End If


    Next cell


End Sub
```

Comment: What is in the `With` block that `.Offset(1, 0)` is referring to? Can you [edit] your question with exactly how you're using the line `Range("C" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value`, i.e. the code that it's in?

Comment: So that's the code I found online with people who have had a similar issue and wanting to refer to the first filtered result. But they were using an AutoFilter, so I don't know if that is what is causing the issue. I probably haven't implemented it into my code correctly. I tried putting it in without a With block like `ws.Range("C" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value`

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with the `With` block? Thanks! And maybe remove a lot of the code that is not pertinent to this specific issue?

Comment: Just edited it now. So the error now is No Cells Were Found

Comment: I figured I'd keep in the code in there for context so that once I am able to refer to the first result, I'll try to make the counter work and if there is any issues with the counter I can keep it within this question submission

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Find row number of first visible row after filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882555/vba-find-row-number-of-first-visible-row-after-filter)

Comment: Their example is using an AutoFilter, would it work the same for a AdvancedFilter?

Comment: Try it. If you can get the row number of first visible row after filtering, then assign a value to a specific cell in that row should be a piece of cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code, you did not **CALL** Filter Data. Your first 2 lines of code should be

```
Public Sub GetNextResult()    

    Call FilterData
```

Comment: Ah I hadn't realised that. So I managed to resolve my initial issue of setting up a variable to be the value of the first result by using this `First_Row_Filtered = Range("C6:C" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlVisible)(1).Value`